# Ironsource integration android version 6.0 - 10

Tags: yandex, ironsource

Please help with the integration of IronSource in android studio. I connect sdk, everything works. reward and interstitial, but only from android version 11 to version 13, and on android version 10 and below, only the banner works, it does not show other formats. What could be the problem?

connected sdk ironsource

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.